# Problem of the Intermediate Value Theorem

Tags: calculus

> Say $f: [0,2] \to R$ continuous, such that $f(0) = f(2)$. Prove that $\exists c ∈ [0,1)$ such that $f(c+1) = f(c)$

I took the function $g(c) =f(c+1) - f(c)$
So what I have to prove is that $\exists c ∈ [0,1)$ such that $g(c)=0$ but I do not know how to proceed

Comment: Did you mean $g(c)=f(c+1)-f(c)$, instead of $g(c)=f(c+1)=f(c)$?

Comment: Indeed, yes that is wha I meant

Comment: And what domain are you using for $g(c)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with the definition

$$
g(c) = f(c+1) - f(c)
$$

Which I think is what you meant.

Now, given that, consider:

What are the possibilities for $g(0)$ ? Well, as with any real number, $g(0)$ could be $0$, less than $0$, or greater than $0$.

So now do the proof with three cases:

- Case 1: $g(0) = 0$. In this case, we don't even need the intermediate value theorem, because $c=0$ works.
- Case 2: $g(0) > 0$. In this case, this means that $f(1) > f(0)$. But then what can we say about $g(1)$? Well, since $f(2) = f(0)$, then $f(1) > f(2)$. So $g(1) = f(2) - f(1) < 0$.

  Now apply the intermediate value theorem to $g$.
- Case 3: $g(0) < 0$. This case is basically a retread of case 2.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** We have $g(0)=-g(1)   $.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

- $g(0)=f(1)-f(0)$
- $g(1)=f(2)-f(1)=f(0)-f(1)=-g(0)$

then since $g(0)=-g(1)$, by IVT exists $c\in(0,1)$ such that $g(c)=0$.